# Storing Session ID in AWS S3 or couchbase. Good idea?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, couchbase

I'm going to introduce the Round Robin Load Balancing in our architecture and I don't really want to use the Sticky Session since we don't utilize the cookie in our apps.  I'm trying to decide whether I should store the session ID for my php apps inside the couchbase database or I should store it in the mounted AWS S3.  Currently our session ID is stored in a pretty standard way which is local server.

I'm thinking of moving the session id storage in the couchbase database, however that requires us to change the code to accomodate that capability.  Storing the session ID on mounted AWS S3 is preferable since I don't really have to change anything in my code other than the pointer in php.ini.  But is it a good idea though and does it has any performance implication to it.  Anyone has any experience with this feature request and perhaps can share your thought/result?

Many thanks everyone...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deciding on how to implement sessions based on what is easy to implement doesn't seem like a very sound basis for choosing an architecture.

S3 -- particularly if you are already using it in a way in which it is not exactly designed to be used (by mounting it, to emulate a filesystem, *which it is not* -- it's an object store) -- does not seem like an appropriate platform for storing session data, for two reasons: the first is the likelihood of potential performance issues, and the second is the consistency model of S3.  A third potential consideration is the per-request pricing for S3, and a fourth consideration is that you'd need to disable any local file cache from s3fs (assuming that's what you're using) or you run the risk of reading stale data... but this would likely introduce additional potential performance issues.

When you create a new object in S3, and then try to download it, it will not necessarily be immediately available in the US Standard Region, which only provides eventual consistency, which means it is sometimes but not always possible to immediately download something you just finished uploading.  The other regions provide read-after-write consistency on new objects, but this could potentially come in the form of a tradeoff that increases the time it takes to initially create the new object, or the initial time to fetch it again.

In contrast to new objects, all regions, not just US Standard, provide only eventual consistency when you overwrite an existing object with different content.  This means if you change the contents of a file on S3 and immediately read the file again, you may not immediately see the newest version of the file... and that if you delete a file and subsequently try to read from it again, you might actually be able to, for a short period of time.  Testing this to disprove whether this is a problem would serve no purpose, since this is their stated consistency model, and behavior you observe today could deteriorate in the future yet still be consistent with their model.

http://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/

By contrast, [SimpleDB](http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/), [DynamoDB](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/), and [RDS](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/) all provide services that are more appropriate for storing session data, with the applicability of each of these services depending on your specific requirements.

Or, you could store the sessions in Couchbase, if that provides suitable performance.  I can't comment on that possibility, since I am unfamiliar with that platform... but S3, in spite of being an excellent service, it does not seem well-suited for this application.

One thing, though...

> we don't utilize the cookie in our apps

I'm skeptical, since that's typically the way sessions work.  How does your server identify the appropriate session for the user connecting to your site, then, if not by a cookie?

Comment: Thanks @Michael - sqlbot for the thought.  What you said is accurate if our server served across different region.  However we architect it so that customer will only hit the aws region based on where they lived so the issue that you described may not be an issue for us.  So basically what you are saying, storing the session in the couchbase is more appropriate than S3?  Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: What I said does not involve whether you "serve across different regions."  The consistency model of S3 applies to *all requests.*  Each region of S3 is independent of the others and S3 does not replicate across regions. The *only* place you will ever find an S3 object is by requesting it from the region where you stored it. The only reason I mentioned regions is that one region has a different consistency model than all the others... I am not saying couchbase is a good choice, since I don't know; I am only saying that S3 is not an appropriate choice.

Comment: Just an update here, S3 now has "strong read-after-write consistency" which is better that it's previous eventual consistency if you're storing session data. Is it wise? That depends on your needs.